# Launch x64 program from the command line?

Tags: .net, windows, x86, 64-bit, 32-bit

I built an x64 program with x64 dependencies.. I can launch it with a "double click" and it works. If I launch it from the command line...

```
D:\myPrograms\MyProgram>MyProgram.exe arg1 arg2
```

... it throws a **TypeInitializationException** when I try to use the types defined in one of the x64 dependencies.

Why would launching from the command line do this? If I explicitly build a program to run x64, why would launching from the command line have the same effect of building it x86?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example